# DDMS button not available

Tags: ddms

I'm just working through my first Android project and when I fire up my Emulator the Android DDMS button should be visible in the top right hand corner next to the Java Perpective button but it isn't there. I checked on installed packages and it is installed but I have obviously missed something in my configuration. If someone can point out where

Answer (score 1):

I found the DDMS by selecting new perpective, selecting Other and then selecting DDMS and the button is now visible. Why it isn't there from the start I don't know but it available now.

Answer (score 1):

It should be under Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> DDMS.
Or you could launch it from the command line. DDMS should be under the `tools/` directory of your SDK. In my computer the SDK is in `Documents/workspace/`, so to launch DDMS i would type

```
Documents/workspace/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ddms
```